# After configuring UEFI to boot from CD I can no longer boot back in Windows 8.1

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, uefi, compact-disc

I have tried changing the settings back but  I still cannot access Windows 8.1
It automatically opens a repair window (with a large unhappy face) which disappears after half a second. The system then reboots and prompts me to choose my keyboard layout. I choose 'US'. It then presents me with 'Troubleshoot' and 'Turn off your PC'.

Comment: Turn UEFI back on but also look for "secure boot". This is the key to returning normal functionality. Alternatively you can often find a "use default values" in your BIOS/EFI firmware configuration pages.

Comment: When I set it to defaults in the UEFI it does not work either.

Comment: Have you returned the boot device order so your HDD is first boot? Have you turned secure boot back on? What's the current settings now you've done a default settings restore?

Comment: I cannot see how to add my HDD in the boot list but the windows boot manager is at the top. Here is what my settings look like: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuo0b.jpg

Comment: What options are under "Secure Boot Mode"?

Comment: Custom and Standard. Neither Work

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by booting from my recovery cd and choosing "automatic repair" in the advanced troubledshooting options.